# ¿Se debe copiar carpeta Metadata a servidores?

Tags: genexus

En una aplicación Web Genexus usando .NET se crea bajo la carpeta "web" una carpeta "Metadata" que dentro tiene 2 carpetas más (Interfaces y TableAccess).

La pregunta es si esa carpeta se debe incluir cuando se instala la aplicación en un servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

la carpeta `Interfaces` es utilizada por el QueryViewer, si lo utilizas, necesitarás llevarla.
Mientras que la carpeta `TableAccess` se utiliza para el cache de datos para los servicios rest de las aplicaciones SD.